# Why do i suddenly need "reboot --force"?

Tags: reboot

Since recently i need to issue ***sudo reboot --force*** in order to reboot my raspberry pi 2 (buster). In the past i could use ***sudo reboot***. How can I find the reason?

When calling sudo reboot without "--force" I am not getting any message. The command simply finishes and i can enter the next command in the shell. The same happens for ***sudo poweroff --force***. In both cases, when i add "--force" the pi reboots or does a poweroff.

I checked the following log files but didn't find any obvious related to the problem:
auth.log, boot.log, debug, faillog, kern.log, messages, syslog, user.log

Answer (score -1):

It appears you're confusing 'reboot' with 'shutdown'. The reboot command does not take any arguments, so 'sudo reboot' should be sufficient to reboot your system immediately. Alternatively, the shutdown command takes parameters (including 'now') to specify a time to shutdown your system (e.g. 'sudo shutdown -r now'). See 'man reboot' and 'man shutdown'.

Try simply using 'sudo reboot' or 'sudo shutdown -r now'. You can check /var/log/syslog for any errors in the shutdown process.

Note: Having said all that, the command 'sudo reboot now' works for me, so apparently the 'now' parameter is just being ignored. Not sure why your system is blocking the reboot when specified.

Comment: *"The reboot command does not take any arguments"* -> I guess `man reboot` is all wrong then (or else someone is trying to re-write the docs without bothering to read them first).

Comment: I updated my question. Your comment is correct regarding the option "now" but the option "--force" indeed exists. It works for reboot and for poweroff (not shutdown as i initially wrote) and is also described in "man reboot"

Comment: Would you care to share your syslog output for when you issue the reboot command? The reboot command without --force still works generally, so this appears to be something specific to your environment that's hanging up the shutdown process.